# iPhone: How to create sandbox environment for inAppPurchase application

Tags: iphone

can you guide me how to create sandbox environment and implement sandbox test in

inAppPurchase application

Comment: the Sandbox is automatically created when you test your in-app purchase in a device. there's no way to test in-app purchases in the simulator.

Comment: thank you JuniorB,i want one more suggestion from you, i am working on augmentation reality app, on camera screen we keep another view for drawing on that and taking screen short it, here my problem is, when i press button on view than it take screen shot, in screen shot it saving image with that button, but i what to save only camera and transparent views only without button, Junior can you guide me to solve this problem with other method r way ..... thank you, have a Nice Day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1)Follow https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf

In this pdf Open "Managing Your In App Purchases" section present in page 134 where you can get all information regarding how to create sandbox test accounts in iTunes Connect.

2)Read [In App Purchase Programing Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/RetrievingStoreInformation/RetrievingStoreInformation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH2-SW1) to implement In App purchase in your application.

3)Finally to ensure that purchases are working correctly, Test your application on actual devices.

Comment: thanks you  Raaz and i want one more suggestion from you, i am working on augmentation reality app, on camera screen we keep another view for drawing on that and taking screen short it, here my problem is, when i press button on view than it take screen shot, in screen shot it saving image with that button, but i have save only camera and transparent views only, Raaz can you guide me to solve this problem with other method r way ..... thank you, have a Nice Day

Comment: @Nandakishore,In this forum you can not ask multiple question in a single thread.the problem you are facing is not related to this question .So post your problem in a different question so that one can give you the right solution .Finally if my answer helps you to solve your problem checkmark it as accepted which is a standard procedure in SO.

Comment: ok, thanks Raaz, next time i will follow yours suggestion and this wont repeat again, Thanks , have a nice day